# Image Service Descriptions

Tags: arcgis-server, image-service

When you load an image service to ArcServer, you have the option to place an Item Description with the service.  This acts as the metadata, however it displays a duplicate: "Service Description"  then right below it "Description"

The information is an exact replication.[image]

When you edit the Item Description of the mosaic dataset and restart the service, both Description blocks update.

How do I edit/remove one of the Description blocks to avoid redundancy?

[image]